# How to add a specific amount of energy to a system?

Tags: thermodynamics, thought-experiment

Say I can measure mass, temperature, and geometrical data over time.

Are there any processes that are known to add a specific amount of heat so I could model the conjugate variables (I am thinking of chemical potential, entropy, pressure).

Please no dependency cycles! I have already found plenty of those (measure heat by using known heat capacity. measure heat capacity by using known heat. ad infinitum...)

Comment: If you haven’t read about Joule’s paddle wheel experiment you might want to start there. If you *have* read about it and don’t think it’s relevant you might want to say why.

Comment: @dmckee I can't really paddle wheel a big chunk of meat, so I have not been able to generalise turning a stick around its axis with a string (which was the experiment if I remember correct). Also I don't know how Joule knew that the paddle wheel was 100% efficient in converting force to heat.

Comment: Metrology isn’t trivial. To measure the specific heat of meat from a standing start you would need several steps. First establish simple mechanical energy standards. Then do a Joule style experiment to learn the specific heat of a fluid. Then do an immersion calorimeter experiment with meat and your known fluid standard to learn the specific heat of flesh. It’s all about bootstrapping.